# ¿Como llamar un Stored Procedure desde c#?

Tags: c#, stored-procedure

¿Cómo puedo llamar el Stored Procedure correctamente desde c#?

Este es el código que tengo:

```
conexion.Open();
string sql = "SELECT * from sp_reporte WHERE facturacion.codigo=('" + codigof.Text+"')  and facturacion.codigo=dtfactura.codigo";
NpgsqlCommand cm = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conexion);
cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cm);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

Así es como tengo el Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTIONs sp_reporte() 
RETURNS void AS $BODY$
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM dtfactura,facturacion WHERE facturacion.codigo=('"+codigof.Text+"')  and facturacion.codigo=dtfactura.codigo ;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: ¿cómo se llama tu procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: se llama sp_reporte asi como esta en el codigo

Comment: Si tienes un stored procedure que se llama `sp_reporte`, no lo puedes llamar desde un `SELECT...`, lo tienes que invocar con un `EXEC sp_reporte ...`

Comment: De igual manera concatenar variables a la cadena que intentas ejecutar, es susceptible a un ataque SQL Injection. Por acá puedes encontrar [más información](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: tienes muy mal el concepto de ejecutar un store procedure, investiga un poco mas, es mas abajo te dieron unas respuestas correctas.

Comment: Tu sp deberia recibir parametros para lo que vos queres hacer. investiga sobre eso. abajo te explicaron como llamarlo. te faltaria solo pasarle parametros

Comment: y en ese caso como hago para traer los datos con SP

Comment: declaras los parámetros en el procedimiento almacenado, luego lo llamas desde C, a cada uno como los escribiste ahi, no se si estas trabajando en capas

Comment: ya definí un parámetro y lo llamo de esta manera 

cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report", Convert.ToInt32(codigof.Text));  no se si asi estara bien

Answer (score 2):

Recomendaria uses el inner join para relacionar las tablas, algo como esto

```
SELECT *
FROM factura f
INNER JOIN detallefactura d ON f.codigofactura = d.codigofactura
WHERE f.codigo= @codigo
```

[PostgreSQL and C# - Working with Result Sets - Npgsql .NET Data Provider](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/npgsql_cs_result_sets)

Para definir el procedure debes usar un cursor de la misma forma a como lo hace Oracle

Analiza el titutlo `Stored Procedure - Working with a Single Result Set in C#` del articulo.

Ademas no creo que estes asignando de forma correcta el parametro en el procedure de la db PostgreSql

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_reporte(codigo integer) RETURNS refcursor AS $$
    DECLARE
      ref refcursor;                                                    
    BEGIN
      OPEN ref FOR SELECT *
                    FROM factura f
                    INNER JOIN detallefactura d ON f.codigofactura = d.codigofactura
                    WHERE f.codigo = codigo;  
      RETURN ref;                                                      
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

y desde codigo .net

```
conexion.Open();

NpgsqlCommand cm = new NpgsqlCommand("sp_reporte", conexion);
cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue(":codigo", int.Parse(codigof.Text));

NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cm);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: Hola **Leandro Tutiini**  tengo un problema y es que no me muestra los datos

Comment: si le quitas el where en el select puedes ver registros ?

Comment: tampoco me deja ver los registros

Comment: no tienes ningun error, o solo esta vacio el datatable. Si defines ese codigo dentro de un try..catch no capturas ningun problema

Comment: lo voy a intentar

Comment: tampoco me manda error, solo lo muestra vació

Comment: mm eso esta muy raro, si tomas el select y lo ejecutas directo en el codigo, sin que este dentro del procedure, como resulta? valida sino se relaciona con los datos en el INNER JOIN, si la relacion no se cumple no mostrara el registro, sino prueba de usar un LEFT JOIN, para ver si es ese el problema

Comment: si ejecuto la consulta directo en el codigo si me muestra los datos aunque tengo que ponerle la condicion

Comment: yo lo hice con la consulta directa en el codigo, si no que me digeron que tiene que ser con el SP

Answer (score 1):

```
    conexion.Open();      
    NpgsqlCommand cm = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conexion);
    cm.CommandText = "sp_reporte";
    cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cm);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
```

Tienes que llamarlo especificando el nombre en el `CommandText`

Comment: pero tengo un problema tengo que ponerle esta condicion   
 facturacion.codigo=('" + codigof.Text+"') hay como tendria que hacer

Comment: ¿como esta tu procedimiento almacenado? la condición debería de estar en el sql, no se que quieres hacer con esa condición, es para que?

Comment: esa condicion es para que me traiga los datos que acado de ingresar